# Drop rows where column value not valid Date Pandas

Tags: pandas, date

I have a dataframe in pandas and I want to delete all the rows from it which doesn't have a valid **date type** value in a particular column. For eg if column under consideration is "E"

If Initial dataframe is this:

[image]

It should become this:

[image]

The date format will always be MM/DD/YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `to_datetime`

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.E, format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
# above will return NaN when the format not match 
df = df[s.notna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using regular expressions:

1. Create a function to check the format

```
def check(column):
  import re
  r = re.compile('.*/.*/')
  if r.match(column) is None:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

2. Apply the function to your DataFramse using `apply()` and drop rows where `check()` return `True`

```
df.drop(df[df["E"].apply(check)].index, inplace=True)
```

In this figure you can see all the steps:
[image: Code]